# What's freaky about Anne Wheeler (Zendaya's character)?

Tags: character, the-greatest-showman

In *The Greatest Showman*, what's freaky about Anne Wheeler (Zendaya's character)? (Or in today's more politically-correct language, what's her disability?)

All I could tell was that she's very acrobatic.

Comment: As far as I can tell..that's it...she's a trapeze artist, nothing more, - http://thegreatestshowman.wikia.com/wiki/Anne_Wheeler

Answer (score 4):

I think it's more about her being an outcast due to her being a person of colour. I think the actress herself is mixed race, although not sure if the character is meant to be too but that would make her even more of a social pariah in the day. Although they skirt around the topic with the language they use, this is the cause of conflict between Phillip and his parents (and the comment about hanging around with "the help").